# using mathematical induction problem with n variable as exponent

Tags: induction

I am a first year Math student and I am looking at problem in my text book which does not have any answers and I have completely no idea how to do this paticular problem.

> Show, using mathematical induction, that for all natural numbers n ≥ 3,
>   $$ 
>   4^2 + 4^3 + 4^4 + · · · + 4^n = \frac{4^2(4^{n-1} -1)}{3}
> $$

Base Case: n=3  $$4^2 + 4^3 = \frac{4^2(4^{n-1} -1)}{3}$$

I understand now

$$ 16 + 64 = 80
$$

Inductive step:

$$\frac{4^2(4^{n-1} -1)}{3}+4^{n+1}=\frac{4^2(4^n -1)}{3}\ .$$
what do I do after this?

Comment: $4^2+4^3=\frac{4^2(4^2-1)}{3}$ When $n=3$

Comment: Yes it works when $n = 3$. What have you done to try and prove this? We need to see more of an attempt on your part.

Comment: Im sorry I do not understand what that means could you show me how I would go about proving this induction ?

I as under the impression when n= 3 the left hand side meant 4^2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For n=3,

$4^2+4^3=\frac{4^2(4^2-1)}{3}$ 
Now for any n=k, assume that, 
$4^2 + 4^3 + 4^4 + · · · + 4^k = \frac{4^2(4^{k-1} -1)}{3}$ 
Now, it has to be true for k+1, 
$4^2+4^3+...+4^k+4^{k+1}=\frac{4^2(4^k-1)}{3}$ 
$\frac{4^2(4^{k-1} -1)}{3}+4^{k+1}=\frac{4^2(4^k-1)}{3}$ 
$3.4^{k+1}=4^2(4^k-1-4^{k-1}+1)$ 
Observe that both sides have been multiplied by $3$ and $4^2$ has been taken common. 
$3.4^{k+1}=4^2(4^k-4^{k-1})$ 
$3.4^{k+1}=4^{k+2}-4^{k+1}$ 
$4.4^{k+1}=4^{k+2}$ 
And thus LHS=RHS.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**.  For the inductive step, you need to prove that
$$\frac{4^2(4^{n-1} -1)}{3}+4^{n+1}=\frac{4^2(4^n -1)}{3}\ .$$

Answer (score 0):

But this is the well known formula for geometric sequence.

$a_1, a_1q, a_1q^2, \ldots, a_1q^{n-2}=a_1\frac{q^{n-1}-1}{q-1}$
with $a_1=4^2$ and $q=4$.